# Question about the null hypothesis of the Ljung–Box test

Tags: time-series, hypothesis-testing, autocorrelation

On [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ljung%E2%80%93Box_test) the null hypothesis of the Ljung Box test is given as:

$H_{0}$: The data are independently distributed (i.e. the correlations in the population from which the sample is taken are 0, so that any observed correlations in the data result from randomness of the sampling process).

1. Why is the null hypothesis "the data are independently distributed" instead of "the data is uncorrelated"?
2. Should a dataset that exhibit heteroskedacity (but where each point is uncorrelated or independent if need be) be expected to pass the test (not reject the null hypothesis), since alternate hypothesis only checks for serial correlation?

Answer (score 3):

Independence of the inputs (typically the errors driving a model rather than the raw data) is used to derive the large-sample Normal distribution of the estimated autocorrelations.  Having uncorrelated observations is *not* enough on its own to guarantee asymptotic Normality, though full independence is indeed stronger than necessary.

I think you're ok with heteroskedasticity if you have independence, at least in large enough samples.

(There's also a practical question: while *as a mathematical condition* being uncorrelated is far weaker than being independent, it's not clear what real-world conditions on data would warrant a belief in uncorrelatedness but not a belief in independence)

Comment: Heteroskedasticity is exactly the prime example ( in time series / finance) of a real world condition where this is not the case

Comment: To be precise "*autoregressive* heteroskedasticity ( not based on covariates x)